# How to troubleshoot "okay google everywhere" missing from voice settings?

Tags: settings, google, google-now, voice-recognition, google-settings

This is what I see:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

And this is what I would like to see:

[image: IMG:]

I am using Motorola Moto G 3rd generation (2015), 1 GB RAM, 8 GB storage; XT1541

I have already tried a few things:

- I'm already using the latest version of Android as of now: 5.1.1 Lollipop.
- I'm using the latest version of the Google now application: 5.1.17.19.arm
- I have tried to search for the magic phrase "okay Google everywhere"
- I have tried to uninstall and reinstalled the Google application. I think it was just a downgrade to version 4 of the app because the Google Play store told me that it is a built in application.
- restarting the Google application by force quitting the app and/or restarting the whole phone.
- switching the local from UK English to US English wherever I could find it in the phone settings.
- and maybe some other things too.

But nothing seemed to help.

What could be causing the missing option? What else could I try to make it show up?

I am also thinking about contacting support. If I do so, should I be contacting Google or Motorola?

**Edit:**

- The version of my "Google Now Launcher" application is 1.1.1.1706998
- I have even tried factory reset with and without restoring from backup; no success.

Comment: I've stumbled upon a whole bunch of your posts on this issue as I try to troubleshoot the exact same problem with my own Moto G3. Have you contacted customer service or otherwise figured anything out?

Comment: Yes, I've contacted Motorola support through chat, phone and email. I didn't receive even remotely the kind of support I'd have liked; let alone a solution. I've contacted Google's online support forum as well, where they seem to have understood the issue I was having much better, but after a while they just stopped responding. No solution from there either.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://www.google.com/settings/accounthistory/audio and turn on voice searches and commands.

Comment: Everything seems to be enabled here already, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: This was already enabled and toggling didn't fix.

Answer (score 1):

flash open gapps on your device the required files for google now from any screen are missing you cannot get them from playstore you need to flash them from recovery